# How can I remove memory bank conflict from the CUDA kernel?

Tags: c++, cuda

The following CUDA kernel seems to have a memory bank conflict.

How can I remove that?

```
__global__ void matrixOuterProductKernel(float* A, float* B, float* C, int K) {
    // Calculate the row and column indices of the current thread
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    // Allocate shared memory for storing the relevant vectors and result fragment
    __shared__ float sA[K][K];
    __shared__ float sB[K][K];
    __shared__ float sC[K][K];
    
    // Initialize the result fragment to zero
    sC[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = 0.0;
    
    // Loop over the necessary vectors and accumulate the result fragment
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        // Load the relevant elements of the vectors into shared memory
        sA[threadIdx.y][i] = A[row * K + i];
        sB[i][threadIdx.x] = B[i * K + col];
        
        // Wait for all threads to finish loading the vectors
        __syncthreads();
        
        // Calculate the outer product and add it to the result fragment
        for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
            sC[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] += sA[threadIdx.y][j] * sB[j][threadIdx.x];
        }
        
        // Wait for all threads to finish the current iteration before loading the next vectors
        __syncthreads();
    }
    
    // Write the result fragment back to global memory
    C[row * K + col] = sC[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x];
}
```

I wrote the following kernel where I tried to remove the memory bank conflict:

```
__global__ void matrixOuterProductKernel(const double* a, const double* b, double* result, const int n) {
    __shared__ double sA[BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE];
    __shared__ double sB[BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE];

    int blockRow = blockIdx.y;
    int blockCol = blockIdx.x;

    int row = threadIdx.y;
    int col = threadIdx.x;

    int globalRow = blockRow * blockDim.y + row;
    int globalCol = blockCol * blockDim.x + col;

    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (n + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
        int aRow = globalRow * n + i * BLOCK_SIZE + col;
        int bCol = (i * BLOCK_SIZE + row) * n + globalCol;

        if (globalRow < n && (i * BLOCK_SIZE + col) < n) {
            sA[row * BLOCK_SIZE + col] = a[aRow];
        } else {
            sA[row * BLOCK_SIZE + col] = 0.0;
        }

        if ((i * BLOCK_SIZE + row) < n && globalCol < n) {
            sB[row * BLOCK_SIZE + col] = b[bCol];
        } else {
            sB[row * BLOCK_SIZE + col] = 0.0;
        }

        __syncthreads();

        for (int j = 0; j < BLOCK_SIZE; j++) {
            sum += sA[row * BLOCK_SIZE + j] * sB[j * BLOCK_SIZE + col];
        }

        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (globalRow < n && globalCol < n) {
        result[globalRow * n + globalCol] = sum;
    }
}
```

**Here, `BLOCK_SIZE` is 32.**

Is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: The first kernel code won't compile, so bank conflicts are rather hypothetical at this point. Whether the second code has bank conflicts or not depends on  the value of `BLOCK_SIZE`, which you have chosen not to show us

Comment: @talonmies, *The first kernel code won't compile* --- why is that?

Comment: Because variable length arrays cannot have static storage duration, and your `__shared__` arrays have static storage duration. And please edit all relevant details into your question, not in comments

Comment: Instead of treating the shared memory as a `[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE]` array, try treating it as a `BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE + 1]` array. That's enough to offset the column-wise accesses by one bank.

Comment: This is explained for example here: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/ Also here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#shared-memory-in-matrix-multiplication-c-aat

Comment: Note that the two kernels aren't equivalent in that the "bank conflict" one is using a 32 bit type, and the "non-bank conflict" one is using a 64 bit type. It isn't possible to eliminate bank conflicts with a 64 bit type, there is a natural 2-way conflict because of the type size

Comment: But a two-way bank conflict is still much better than a 32-way conflict